# kubectl: how does it discover the incluster config?

Tags: python, kubernetes, subprocess, config, kubectl

When I run `kubectl` inside of a pod it defaults to "in-cluster config" (defined by files in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount`). If I want to wrap `kubectl` inside of a call to Python subprocess with `shell=False`, how do I tell `kubectl` where to find the in-cluster config?

Since when I run `shell=False` none of the environment makes it into the subprocess. It seems I need to explicitly pass some environment variables or other system state to the subprocess call for `kubectl` to discover the in-cluster config.

How does `kubectl` discover this config? Are there a simple few variables to pass through?

Comment: If it fits your use case: Have you considered using the kubernetes Python client package to interact with the API instead of wrapping the kubectl command using subprocess? Here’s an example of using the Python package in-cluster: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/in_cluster_config.py.

Comment: Yes, I was originally using the python client, but I had to abandon it in this specific case. The Python client does not support the 'kubectl apply' functionality, where it will create or mutate existing resources given an arbitrary yaml file containing one or more k8s object definitions. (The python client does have a "create_from_yaml.py" which is useful, but it does not handle updating existing resources)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to construct a `KUBECONFIG` by hand, given those values, since that's more-or-less exactly what the [python client does anyway](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/blob/474e9fb32293fa05098e920967bb0e0645182d5b/config/incluster_config.py#L81-L86). In short, either in python or via the following commands:

```sh
kubectl config set-cluster the-cluster --server="https://${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST}:${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT}" --certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
kubectl config set-credentials pod-token --token="$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)"
kubectl config set-context pod-context --cluster=the-cluster --user=pod-token
kubectl config use-context pod-context
```

and then you're off to the races